# how to get clion to show elements after the first in the debugger from a pointer?

Tags: c++, clion

I have a pointer which points to a memory containing 2 ints. Clion's debugger shows the first element, but I want to see the second one as well. When I use an array however, Clion shows both. Any ideas?
[image]

[image]

Comment: As indicated by the hint on that text field above the variables, you can probably add a watch by typing `z[1]` there and then clicking Ctrl+Shift+Enter. The debugger can't do this automatically, because it can't know that the pointer points to an array and how big that array would be.

Comment: I don't know about clion. In Visual Studio debugger you can specify the number of items that shall be display with a comma and the number. Probably clion has a similar feature. Try `z,2` as the expression to be watched.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom watcher (in the debug window) for z[1] by clicking the plus icon and setting it to the variable you want to see on every debug session